# Loading Local Files on Android With Local HTML - net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, android-webview

Placing my project in a folder the main root directory, I have created a simple hello world project. The Html file when loaded into chrome works great, however, loading files in the main project folder or subfolders give a net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I would like to have video autoplay in the background with a basic overlay & buttons (already set to go & works on desktop).

Tried moving the file locations to the main folder & renamed the directories to not have spaces.

Also tried using file:/// instead of opening through a file explorer in chrome.

Using Android v10 on Pixel 2XL

```
<body>
<div id="mainCont">
<spread class="header">Main Test</spread><br>
<button> <a href="ALTs/L1.html">Layout 1</a></button>
</div>

<div>
  <video playsinline autoplay muted loop id="bgVideo">
    <source src="Link/VerticalTest.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
</body> 

<style>

  @font-face {
    font-family: Lato;
    src:  url(/FontRef/ProximaNova-Bold.otf) format('opentype'),
          url(/FontRef/ProximaNova-Light.otf) format('opentype'),
          url(/FontRef/ProximaNova-Reg.otf) format('opentype'),
          url(/FontRef/ProximaNova-It.otf) format('opentype'),
          url(/FontRef/ProximaNova-Sbold.otf) format('opentype'),
  }

body{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: ProximaNova-Reg, sans-serif;
}

#bgVideo {
  z-index:-1;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#mainCont{
padding: 5em;
z-index:10000;
positoin: absolute;
top:50%;
transform: translateY(100%);
}

a{
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
}


button{
  padding:10px;
  margin:2em;
  color: #494949 !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid white !important;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s
}
button:hover{
  color: #ffffff !important;
  background: #f6b93b;
  border-color: #f6b93b !important;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.header{
font-family: ProximaNova-Sbold, sans-serif;
font-size: calc(2.87em - 1vw);
color:white;
font-weight:400;
text-transform:uppercase;
letter-spacing:.6em;
margin-top:calc(6em - 1vw);
}
```

Using the remote debugger in chrome on my android device, net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND is the only issue that I receive for the video file. No such error for the fonts which are being applied for some reason?

Comment: enable javascript for webview and then try again

Answer (score 0):

I've always placed my files in the android 'assets' folder.  Then, you can do something like this for the HTML:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/L1.html");
```

Or if you are referencing image or movie files, I've used something like this:

```
@SuppressLint({ "SetJavaScriptEnabled", "DefaultLocale" })
private void displayDetail()
{           

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        String imageName = animalName.toLowerCase();
        imageName = imageName.replaceAll(" ", "_");
        imageName = imageName.replaceAll("-", "_");
        imageName = imageName.replaceAll("\\(", "");
        imageName = imageName.replaceAll("\\)", "");
        imageName = imageName + ".jpg";

        String html = "<html><body style='font-size: 18px; font-family: \"arial\";'><center><img alt='Embedded Image' src='" + imageName + "'/></center><br><div style='position: relative; margin-left: 10px; margin-right:10px;'>" + breedDetails + "</div></body></html>";

        String mime = "text/html";
        String encoding = "utf-8";

        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, mime, encoding, null);


}
```

Also ensure you have permission to read from external storage.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify; I am opening this as a raw .html file stored on the device with its linked files also on there.

I am not using Android Studio to build this, but totally understand that is waaayyyy better for a final project lol. Thank you for this answer though!

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification.  For images, you could try converting your images into base64 encoded strings, then adding those strings into your html with src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/....."